# Laravel admin pannel how to create

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I am using Laravel as a Backend and Angularjs as a Frontend.

I am Using this full package https://github.com/andbet39/tokenAuth for my Local setup AWT authendication it working fine,

How to do admin authendication and redirect to admin page?

How to do in Admin Panel

Comment: this is a wide problem and not a question, people cannot answer this. You should do more research on how things work and come up with constructive questions which are answerable as well as help other too.

Comment: For authentication you can use https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth ,  In api base system don't use redirection, it needs to handle by frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have choices to make here.

There are [several packages out there](https://packagist.org/?q=laravel%20admin&p=0) that can provide a full fledged admin panel for you (e.g. TCG/Voyager).

Or you could build one yourself with Laravel/Angular, this way you can customize the way you want.

The question I'm sensing here (you didn't state one clear enough) is:

> How do I redirect to my admin panel?

The anwser to that comes down to this.
You need to have a route protected by auth middleware

```
# L5
Route::middleware(['auth'])->get('/admin', 'AdminController@index)->name('admin.index');
```

And put the redirect in your controller

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    (..)
    return redirect(route('admin.index'));
}
```

After a successful login, the user get's redirected to the admin page.
Since this is a very basic example you should add more validation based on if the user is allowed to even view the admin page. But that is for a later stage :)